# Deviation from law of reflection in (non-perfect) inelastic collisions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, reflection

[Does the law of reflection hold for balls bouncing inelastically on inclined planes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318493)

In the above question, an answer included the following paragraph:

> The law of reflection only holds if the collision is elastic and the object which the ball collides with does not move. If the collision is not elastic then the perpendicular component of velocity is smaller after than before, whereas the parallel component is the same. So when $e<1$ the angle of reflection is greater than the angle of incidence.

The context is a particle on a flat plane colliding on a wall.

For inelastic collisions, I am convinced that the perpendicular component of velocity will be smaller, but will the parallel component really remain the same?

After all, the surface may not be completely smooth.